# Do I need Tomcat for developing Servlet(rest server) using Jetty?

Tags: java, rest, websocket, jetty

I try to make rest Server using jetty ans javax-rs.
I refer to contents of some sites.

https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2015/03/creating-web-services-and-a-rest-server-with-jax-rs-and-jetty.html

I am just having some questions.
1. If I want to make it, Do I have to run tomcat or just OK using Jetty?

2. I want to set configure for WebSocket and rest server. It means not only using rest server but also using websocket. I don't know how to set to use both.
   First of all, I successfully made web socket server.

**I want to know merger of two different codes below.**

my Server main is like this for using websocket(it was referred to this sites http://amilamanoj.blogspot.kr/2013/06/secure-websockets-with-jetty.html)

```
import org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpVersion;
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.*;
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler;
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection;
import org.eclipse.jetty.util.resource.FileResource;
import org.eclipse.jetty.util.resource.Resource;
import org.eclipse.jetty.util.ssl.SslContextFactory;
import org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.server.WebSocketHandler;
import org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.servlet.WebSocketServletFactory;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class WebSocketServer {
    private Server server;
    private String host;
    private int port;
    private Resource keyStoreResource;
    private String keyStorePassword;
    private String keyManagerPassword;
    private List<Handler> webSocketHandlerList = new ArrayList<>();

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        WebSocketServer webSocketServer = new WebSocketServer();
        webSocketServer.setHost("localhost");
        webSocketServer.setPort(8443);
        webSocketServer.setKeyStoreResource(new FileResource(WebSocketServer.class.getResource("/keystore.jks")));
        webSocketServer.setKeyStorePassword("password");
        webSocketServer.setKeyManagerPassword("password");
        webSocketServer.addWebSocket(MyWebSocket.class, "/");
        webSocketServer.initialize();
        webSocketServer.start();
    }

    public void initialize() {
        server = new Server();
        // connector configuration
        SslContextFactory sslContextFactory = new SslContextFactory();
        sslContextFactory.setKeyStoreResource(keyStoreResource);
        sslContextFactory.setKeyStorePassword(keyStorePassword);
        sslContextFactory.setKeyManagerPassword(keyManagerPassword);
        SslConnectionFactory sslConnectionFactory = new SslConnectionFactory(sslContextFactory, HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1.asString());
        HttpConnectionFactory httpConnectionFactory = new HttpConnectionFactory(new HttpConfiguration());
        ServerConnector sslConnector = new ServerConnector(server, sslConnectionFactory, httpConnectionFactory);
        sslConnector.setHost(host);
        sslConnector.setPort(port);
        server.addConnector(sslConnector);
        // handler configuration
        HandlerCollection handlerCollection = new HandlerCollection();
        handlerCollection.setHandlers(webSocketHandlerList.toArray(new Handler[0]));
        server.setHandler(handlerCollection);
    }

    public void addWebSocket(final Class<?> webSocket, String pathSpec) {
        WebSocketHandler wsHandler = new WebSocketHandler() {
            @Override
            public void configure(WebSocketServletFactory webSocketServletFactory) {
                webSocketServletFactory.register(webSocket);
            }
        };
        ContextHandler wsContextHandler = new ContextHandler();
        wsContextHandler.setHandler(wsHandler);
        wsContextHandler.setContextPath(pathSpec);  // this context path doesn't work ftm
        webSocketHandlerList.add(wsHandler);
    }

    public void start() throws Exception {
        server.start();
        server.join();
    }
    public void stop() throws Exception {
        server.stop();
        server.join();
    }

    public void setHost(String host) {
        this.host = host;
    }
    public void setPort(int port) {
        this.port = port;
    }
    public void setKeyStoreResource(Resource keyStoreResource) {
        this.keyStoreResource = keyStoreResource;
    }
    public void setKeyStorePassword(String keyStorePassword) {
        this.keyStorePassword = keyStorePassword;
    }
    public void setKeyManagerPassword(String keyManagerPassword) {
        this.keyManagerPassword = keyManagerPassword;
    }

}
```

And this is configuration for running Rest Server.

```
package example;
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server;4
import org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler;

import org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder;

public class RestServer {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        ServletContextHandler context = new ServletContextHandler(ServletContextHandler.SESSIONS);

        context.setContextPath("/");



        Server jettyServer = new Server(8080);

        jettyServer.setHandler(context);



        ServletHolder jerseyServlet = context.addServlet(

                org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.class, "/*");

        jerseyServlet.setInitOrder(0);



        jerseyServlet.setInitParameter(

                "jersey.config.server.provider.classnames",

                Calculator.class.getCanonicalName());
        try {

            jettyServer.start();

            jettyServer.join();

        } finally {

            jettyServer.destroy();

        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Jetty and Tomcat are both servlet/JSP engines.  You would choose one or the other; you don't need both.  Jetty alone is fine.

Comment: Well, it can get confusing, as Tomcat and Jetty both use the Apache Jasper JSP engine.  The JSP setup you see in Jetty embedded mode is to satisfy the Jasper JSP engine requirements.